# Changing bluetooth device name

Tags: linux, bluetooth

How can the friendly device name of a remote Bluetooth device be changed (using a command-line tool in Linux or similar)? I have looked at some of the software included in `bluez-tools` such as `hcitool` and `bt-device`, but none of these have the feature to change the remote device name. There does not seem to be any HCI command for doing this either.

I am aware of that it is possible to change the alias of devices in many bluetooth managers, but that is not the same thing. The alias is only visible on the local computer, while the device name is visible to all new devices.

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/80963/18339) on Ask Ubuntu should work with just one step.

Answer (score 12):

Use bt-device (part of the `bluez-tools` package).

Get a list of paired devices:

```
bt-device -l
```

To set the new alias:

```
bt-device --set macaddress|name Alias "New Name"
```

ie:

```
bt-device --set S530 Alias "S530 Blue"
```

Comment: HOWEVER: although this works for almost every other bluetooth tool, it appears that the bluetooth gui manager that comes installed on MintOS does not actually display the Alias (which can be changed) but the default Name, which cannot.

Comment: Does not affect Ubuntu 20.04 'Settings - Bluetooth Devices' name, although 'bt-device -l' shows alias has been set and 'sudo service bluetooth restart' has been done. .

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 'Settings - Bluetooth Devices' displays the bluetooth remote device name, not the alias, so changing the alias has no visible effect. The bluetooth remote device name is _[ro]_ (read-only), see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/bt-device.1.html

Answer (score 8):

Answering over half a year later, but better late than never. It may help other people.

This answer is based on this [blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20151005203615/https://alexborisov.org/how-to-change-the-bluetooth-device-name-on-linux-mint-13-and-ubuntu-12/). It worked for me. In a very Linux-y style of doing things, it's based on editing configuration files rather than using a tool.

You need to edit two files:

- In `/var/lib/bluetooth/[your MAC address]/config`, edit the line that starts with `name`.
- In `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` change the line with `Name = %h-%d` so that it reads only `Name = %h`, assuming you want to use your hostname as your bluetooth name (the `%d` adds a different index for each local bluetooth adapter, but you probably only have one). Using something else should work, but I haven't tried that myself.

Once you're done, restart the bluetooth service:

```
$ sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Comment: This works for bluez5 (I see the changed name when scanning from another device). While I'm happy that you wrote this I'm sad that setting the name in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf has no effect. :(

Answer (score 6):

On Fedora I use the command `bluetoothctl` to change these settings.
This is provided by the package `bluez`, and in my case it was already installed.

`bluetoothctl` has a prompt that is accessed simply by running the command.
Its commands can also be used without accessing the prompt, but that way there is no autocompletion.

There is a distinction between external **devices** (mouse, keyboard, gamepad, etc.), and the host **controllers** (built-in BT card, external USB BT adapter, etc.).

With `bluetoothctl` is possible to change both device and controller alias, the process can be summed up in 3 steps:

- list the available controller/devices
- select the controller/device to modify
- modify the controller/device

The commands are:

##### Controller

- run `bluetoothctl` to access its prompt
- run `list` to list the available controllers

  - in my case I only have 1 controller, my laptop's BT card
- run `select 00:11:22:33:44:55` to select the controller to modify

  - the address can be autocompleted with `TAB`, in my case is the only 1 address available
- run `system-alias "new alias for my BT controller"` to modify the controller alias

##### Device

- run `bluetoothctl` to access its prompt
- run `devices` to list the available devices

  - the output can be filtered by using optional properties, for example `devices Connected`
- run `connect AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF` to select the devices to modify

  - the address can be autocompleted with `TAB`
- run `set-alias "new alias for my BT device"` to modify the device alias

---

`help` can be used to get an overview of the available commands:

```
[bluetooth]# help
Menu main:
Available commands:
-------------------
...
list                                              List available controllers
...
select <ctrl>                                     Select default controller
devices [Paired/Bonded/Trusted/Connected]         List available devices, with an optional property as the filter
system-alias <name>                               Set controller alias
reset-alias                                       Reset controller alias
...
set-alias <alias>                                 Set device alias
...
connect <dev>                                     Connect device
...
```

Comment: `set-alias` works in Fedora so I can see the new name in the UI menu

Comment: You can also edit `/var/lib/bluetooth/$ADAPTER_MAC/$DEVICE_MAC/info` and add a line in `[General]`: `Alias=My New Alias`, followed by `systemctl restart bluetooth`. (Tested under Fedora 39)